# How do I preserve the leading zeros when I insert a number into this table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have inserted two records into a table.

```
create table num(id int)
insert into num values(0023)
insert into num values(23)
select * from num
```

When I query them, they all display as `23`. It means that SQL Server ignores the leading 0s. What's the mechanism behind that? How can I have SQL Server return the values as I inserted them (i.e. `0023` and `23`)?

Comment: Why do you care about the leading zeros?  If they are meaningful to your system, then `id` should be of type `VARCHAR` or similar.

Comment: Exactly how do you expect 0023 to be encoded in the database as something different from 23 or 023 or 0000000023? They all represent the same NUMBER. And int is a NUMBER data type. There's no place for the server to store this "leading number of decimal zeroes" value.

Comment: This is a poor question, and would have been covered in any introduction to programming class. An int can never store leading zeros, because of the nature of ints. This can be solved by looking at any number of web resources. This does not need the input of a database administrator.

Comment: Leading zeroes are implied. Besides using a string instead, if you needed a specific number of leading zeroes, that is extra information beyond what is stored in an int column. One option is using a string column, but another option is storing the number of leading zeroes in either another column, or in the UI. if the UI always formats to 4 digits with padding leading zeroes, for example, then you have stored this information in the UI. If you need the # of zeroes to vary and be preserved for each record, you can store that info in a separate field instead.

Answer (score 28):

`0023` is not a number. It's a string. `23` is the number. SQL Server is able to recognize that those extra zeros are not needed to define the number, so it ignores them. If you want to dispaly a value as 0023 to the application, I'd suggest doing the formatting on the application side. That way the number stored in SQL Server is still a number if you want do addition, aggregation, or other calculations. If you really have to store it as '`0023`', you need to convert it to a character field; char, varchar, nvarchar, nchar.

Comment: If the 0023 is string,how can I insert the value into the table which I have defined the id as int format?

Comment: @user8365 - Either define `id` as `VARCHAR` or just insert 23 instead of 0023

Comment: @user8365 - You're asking if you can make SQL Server violate the [domain integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrity_constraints#Domain_Integrity) of that field.  You can't. If `0023` is a string then store it as a string.  If it isn't, then store it as an INT and forget about the leading zeros.

Comment: Exactly what @NickChammas said. You don't have any choice here. 23 is a number, 0023 is a string. If you want a number, treat it as a number. Like my answer says, if it needs to sort like a number, add, subtract, multiply, divide, etc., like a number, then it needs to be a number. No choices. No arguments. Leading zeros is just formatting. Do that in app code or somewhere.

Comment: @Grant I cannot agree that the leading zeroes are just formatting. They are legitimate in any numeral system; however, 0023b10 = 23b10; so, any storage system gains some degree of compression by not encoding all the leading zeroes. So, fundamentally our questioner is asking the wrong question. Why is 0023 not an integer? It is an integer! We just don't need to encode an infinity of leading numerals to represent it as such.

Comment: @ooutwire Sure, in a scientific and theoretical sense, it's a number. But you're talking to a nuke machinist mate, film school drop-out, completely self-taught in comptuters. Number theory is all well & good and important, but at the end of the day 0023 is not treated like 23. I'll leave the rest to you guys with real educations.

Comment: @Grant No insult intended (cu @ at the SqlSat 111 spkrs din =-). What I really want to say to the questioner is that the IEEE standard used by SQL Server et al. considers an integer to be a decimal number with its radix (decimal) point to the right of the least sig fig (23 really is 23.). If you say insert 023 into an int-type col, the engine will compress the number by stripping the 0, since the number is defined as an int. So, basically, if you want leading zeroes, then use , eg, decimal(8,4) & insert .0023, then multiply by 10,000, which would give 0023.; but this would just be silly.

Answer (score 6):

It was already said in other answers that `00023` is a number; I just want to add that you can use computed columns to show that number using custom format. For example,

```
create table num_table(id int not null primary key identity(1,1),
num int, leading_zeros smallint,
constraint chk_leading_zero_nonnegative check (leading_zero>=0),
num_formatted as replicate('0',coalesce(leading_zeros,0)) +cast(num as varchar(10)));
insert into num_table(num,leading_zeros) values(23,2) ;
select num_formatted from num_table; -- output '0023'
```

Comment: Good point, absolutely worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

0023 is a number but the int and other number data types do not store leading zeroes since there is no mathematical reason to do so.

If you need to store leading zeroes use a string data type like, char, varchar etc

Comment: If we assume that `INT` is fixed-length (like 32 bits) and binary notation is used for storing them, then leading zeroes are indeed stored. But they are not displayed in the output.

Comment: @ypercube - Right, but the number of leading zeros is simply what's required to fill the 32 bits (as opposed to user-definable).

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, no argue there. I think the point is NOT whether or not leading zeroes are stored. It's whether two versions of the same number can be stored in the datatype, one with and one without leading zeroes.

Comment: But this makes no sense. Two decimal leading zeroes has absolutely no relation to the number of leading zeroes in a 32-bit integer. Consider the decimal number `15`--this only takes one digit in hexadecimal, `F`. They already have a different number of "leading zeroes." 2147483647 is 10 digits, but in hex that's only 7FFFFFFF or 8 digits.

Comment: Fundamentally, one must consider the mathematical numeral system which we are using...in this case decimal (base 10). 23 is a decimal number; it is 0x1000 + 0x100 + 2x10 + 3 = 23. In octal, it is 2X8 + 3 and so on. So, to say to the storage engine, "store 23 with two leading zeroes" is not useful, since it merely encodes the same final result, that is 23. SQL Server does not ignore your zeroes, it merely returns to you a decimal value equal to the number which you inserted, i.e., 0023 or 23.